# Regarding Users

Tags: customer-portal, user, partner-portal, userlicense, high-volume-portal

What is the Difference Between Portal User,Partner User,Customer Community User,High Volume Standard Portal User,How to Login with the Different types Of Users ,why these Many types of Users Needed In Salesforce? Cananyone Describe Me?

Answer (score 1):

All of those are the different licenses which decide different features and object access in the Salesforce Communities.

When a user is created when he signs up for the community, it automatically assign a license to the created user depending on your community configuration.

This article should help :

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US

I Hope it helps.